# POST http://localhost:3000/api/register 404 (Not Found) how to fix this error

Tags: javascript, axios

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nphXn.png)

https://github.com/akashyap2013/MERN_Login_App_with_ResetEmail.git

the problem in register.js
the error show in console as xhr.js:251

```
    POST http://localhost:3000/api/register 404 (Not Found)
```

data sent backend by postman correctly. But face this issue in frontend

Comment: Seems like your server is listening for 8080 port, not 3000?

Comment: yes server running and connect to mongodb on port 8080

Comment: So why you request port 3000 then? :)

Comment: in  .env file I give as REACT_APP_SERVER_DOMAIN='http://localhost:8080'                     can you say then where should i change in my code part

Answer (score 0):

Which port is your server running on?
If your server is running on port 8080, replace "3000" with "8080".

Comment: yes port running on 8080.Every place i give as 8080.I can't found in where should i change

Comment: How have you used Axios requests?

Comment: in .env file ,REACT_APP_SERVER_DOMAIN='localhost:8080'                                                in helper.js  , axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_DOMAIN;

Comment: /** register user function */
export async function registerUser(credentials){
    try {
        const { data : { msg }, status } = await axios.post(`/api/register `, credentials);

        let { username, email } = credentials;

        /** send email */
        if(status === 201){
            await axios.post('/api/registerMail', { username, userEmail : email, text : msg})
        }

        return Promise.resolve(msg)
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject({ error })
    }
}

Comment: how can I contact you